# how to print TD in PHP or laravel in Below Format?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

suppose I have data from 1 to 10 and I like to print in the below style

| Data Header | Data Header | Data Header | Data Header | Data Header |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

| SixData Header | Data Header | Data Header | Data Header | Data Header |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |

I have a loop like this it prints each element in a row

```xml
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Data Header</th>
    <th>Data Header</th>
    <th>Data Header</th>
    <th>Data Header</th>
    <th>Data Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Data Header</th>
    <th>Data Header</th>
    <th>Data Header</th>
    <th>Data Header</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach ($number as $n)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$n->number}}
    <tr>
  @endforeach
</table>
```

I have an array that gets data from the controller that don't know the length, it should repeat the same pattern the only 5 TD in a row, how to display in php or in laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the collection's `chunk()` method. Assumming `$number` is a `Collection`.

```xml
@foreach($number->chunk(5) as $chunk)
  <table>
    <tr>
      @foreach(range(1, $chunk->count()) as $rows)
        <th>Data header</th>
      @endforeach
    </tr>
    <tr>
      @foreach($chunk as $n)
        <td>{{ $n }}</td>
      @endforeach
    </tr>
  </table>
@endforeach
```

If `$number` is just an array, do `@foreach(collect($number)->chunk(5) as $chunk)` instead.